# Using array_map to replace spaces between characters

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm creating an array from a string with comma separated values

```
$result = "apple, hello word, 80, apple";    

$result = str_getcsv($result); //create array     
$result = array_filter(array_map('trim', $result)); //remove whitespaces
```

Some characters in a value have spaces between them, like `hello world` and I want to replace the spaces with a dash (to make the the string URL friendly.) Example: `hello-world`

I thought of iterating through the array using `str_replace` but can it be done better using `array_map` like I'm doing to trim?

Comment: You could write a function to perform the processing you want, or use a Closure (anonymous function) if you are on PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can work directly on arrays as well:

```
$result = str_replace(' ', '-', $result);
```

This will have the same result as the less readable

```
$result = array_map(function($el) { return str_replace(' ','-',$el); }, $result);
```

Both are also equivalent to the classic

```
foreach($result as &$element) {
    $element = str_replace(' ', '-', $element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function urlFrendly($str){
    return str_replace(' ', '-', $str);
}

$result = "apple, hello word, 80, apple";    

$result = str_getcsv($result); //create array     
$result = array_filter(array_map('trim', $result)); //remove whitespaces
$result = array_map('urlFrendly', $result); 
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = "apple, hello word, 80, apple";
$replaced = preg_replace('/\s*([[:alpha:]]+) +([[:alpha:]]+)\s*/', '\\1-\\2',$result);
$array = str_getcsv($replaced);
print_r($array);
```

output:

```
Array
(
[0] => apple
[1] => hello-word
[2] => 80
[3] => apple
)
```